# On the justification of negation introduction

Tags: logic

In *forall x: Calgary, by P. D. Magnus*, section **16.6** p. 153, appears this natural deduction proof using Fitch-style:

[image]

Shouldn't line 8 be *Indirect Proof* because he is not introducing a negation ?

Comment: It is introducing negation, particularly, $\lnot \lnot(A\lor \lnot A) \equiv (A\lor \lnot A)$, albeit, the text doesn't list these two steps, the first being $\lnot$ I, the second being DN (double negation).

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Thank you, it is on p. 153.

Comment: Ok, I was browsing a different version :-) In my "Calgary" page 153 is the first page of FOL... Having said that, based on the Appendix **Basic deduction rules for TFL** (end of the book), you are still right: the rule "if from $\lnot \mathcal A$ we have derived $\bot$, conclude with $\mathcal A$" is called **Indirect proof**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, according to their definitions, it should be IP. In the development of the proof on the pages before, it actually does have $IP$ instead of $\neg I$ in the last line, so the $IP$ label in the finished proof is likely a typo.

That being said, one can define $IP$ in terms of $\neg I$, but with an additional step, double negation elimination ($DNE$):

```
m   | | ¬A
    | |---
    | | ...
n   | | ⊥
n+1 | ¬¬A    (¬I, m-n)
n+2 | A      (DNE, n+1)
```

where $DNE$ means going from $\neg \neg A$ to $A$.

But since $DNE$ is an additional (implicit) inference step that isn't valid in all logics that have $\neg I$ (namely in intuitionistic logic), one shouldn't conflate $IP$ with $\neg I$, and they don't do so in their rule definitions -- so this an inconsistency, and probably an error.